# Joining and ordering data from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my DB structure:

```
table: events
    id
    title
    category_id

table: categories
    id
    name

table: promoters
    id
    name
    avatar

table: dates
    id
    startdate
    enddate
```

Every Event can have one Category and many promoters, dates.

then for dates and promoters I use two pivot tables:

```
table: event_promoter
    id
    event_id
    promoter_id

table: event_date
    id
    event_id
    date_id
```

I need to retrieve all events with promoters and categories fields ordered by dates (taking only dates > today date). Looking for query help.

**UPDATE EXAMPLE**

Two events:

```
Table Events
id  | title                  | category_id
1   | StackOverflow Meeting  | 1
2   | Easter Party           | 2

Table Categories
id  | name  
1   | Festival
2   | Professional

Table Promoters
id  | name       | Avatar  
1   | Joe Smith  | file1.jpg
2   | Frank White| file2.jpg
3   | Mike Red   | file3.jpg

Table Dates
id  | start      | end  
1   | 01-24-2018 | 01-27-2018
2   | 04-24-2018 | 04-27-2018
3   | 04-18-2018 | 04-19-2018

table: event_promoter
    id  | event_id   |  promoter_id
    1   | 1          |  1
    2   | 1          |  3
    3   | 2          |  2

table: event_date
    id  | event_id   |  date_id
    1   | 1          |  1
    2   | 1          |  2
    3   | 2          |  3
```

My query need to have first "easter party" because of the date(id:3), then in my events list I've:

('Easter Party', 'StackOverflow Meeting')

with all associated relational fields.

Comment: Off topic: pivot tables? those are linking tables or relation tables.. pivot is completly different.

Comment: On topic: Can you post example data as ascii data tables and expected result also as a ascii table table.

Comment: @RaymondNijland We often call them pivot tables. All tables in a relational database are relational. That why it's called a relational database.

Comment: Some reference on "my concept" of pivot table:
http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Well guess i have some other definitions then @Strawberry i call tables that contain one-to-many or many-to-many relations linking or relation tables.. And tables that really contain a pivot method a pivot table.

Comment: @RaymondNijland There's nothing wrong with your definitions - and I agree that's it's a bit confusing to have the same terms meaning different things. But given the context, we generally understand what's meant.

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: there's no relation between category and events?

Comment: missed a field, I've category_id on events table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to reference the category on the events table, by adding a category_id column in the events table.
Also, you dont need an id column in event_promoter and in event_dates. Remove that column and make the two remaining columns the primary key.

Then, the simplest way of doing it will by a inner join:

```
select events.id, events.title, 
categories.name as category, 
GROUP_CONCAT(dates.startdate separator ',') as startdate, 
GROUP_CONCAT(dates.enddate separator ',') as enddate, 
GROUP_CONCAT(promoters.name separator ',') as promoter, 
GROUP_CONCAT(promoters.avatar separator ',') as avatar
from events
inner join categories on events.category_id = categories.id
inner join event_dates on events.id = event_dates.event_id
inner join dates on event_dates.date_id = dates.id 
inner join event_promoter on events.id = event_promoter.event_id 
inner join promoters on event_promoter.promoter_id = promoters.id
where dates.startdate > now()
group by events.id
order by dates.startdate
```

Comment: Still using the old ansi comma join instead of INNER JOIN syntax. The old comma join syntax is harder to read and eazier to mis you are joining the tables.

Comment: @DioneiMiodutzki thanks, your answer is near to my goal, but my start date is a text. Do I need to use something like STR_TO_DATE?

Comment: Yes, you will need to convert it with str_to_date

Comment: Just tested, it works but the query show the same event many time, how to group by event_id? @DioneiMiodutzki

Comment: It depends of what info you will need. If you need all dates and promoters data, you will have to agregate them in a string or array and then divide them again in the software.
Changed the query, give it a try.